# Compare a variables in bash

Tags: bash, variables, compare

I have this code. But I cant get the result i need.
Im comparing variables in bash.
If the number i get from a webpage is greater than 40 i want a yes.

```
var2=40
maj=$(curl $1)
var1=$(echo "$maj" | grep "[0-9]" | awk '{print $3}')
echo $var1
if [[ "$var1" > "$var2" ]]; then
echo "yes"
else
echo "no"
fi
```

$1 could be:

```
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=heH8s5yy
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k5dkKUu1
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=59V0eJmz
```

the thing is when i do

```
./test.sh http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k5dkKUu1
```

i get yes

and 5 is less than 40

Answer (score 6):

This is because the `>` symbol inside double brackets `[[ ... ]]` does lexicographical comparison. You need to use the `-gt` operator to compare numerical values, like this:

```
[[ $var1 -gt "$var2" ]]
```

It is even better to do numeric operations inside double parenthesis, like this

```
if (( var1 > var2 ))
```